# If $ a^2 + b^2=1,c^2+d^2=1,ac+bd=0 $ , find $ab+cd $?

Tags: polynomials, systems-of-equations

I have tried everything except trigonometry.We have not still started doing trigonometry in classes.
I don't know how am I supposed to solve this,since I put 5 hours and nothing led to solution.

Comment: A geometric hint: $(a,b)$ and $(c,d)$ are points on the unit circle $x^2+y^2=1$. Can you find points that satisfy $ac+bd=0$? What properties do they have to satisfy?

Comment: $(a,b)$ and $(c,d)$ are points on a unit circle centered at the origin. That means every point of the circle is on a line of the form $y=mx$ passing through the origin for some slope $m$. So $b=ma$ and $c=nd$ $ac+bd=0\implies  b/a=-c/d$. That implies $mn=-1$. If the product of slopes of two lines is $-1$, then the lines are perpendicular. Put another way, the arclength of the circle between  any two qualifying pairs of points is $\pi/2$.

Answer (score 2):

If $b\ne 0$ then $d=-{ac\over b}$ so $$ c^2+{a^2c^2\over b^2}=1\implies c^2=b^2$$

Now $$ab+cd = ab-{ac^2\over b}  = {a(b^2-c^2)\over b}=0$$

Now try if $b=0$ by yourself.

Comment: Thank you,is it possible to solve equations with only elimination without substitution?

Comment: Why?.................

Answer (score 1):

$ab+cd=0$ because
\begin{align*}
cd
&=cd(a^2+b^2)\\
&=a(ac)d+(bd)bc\\
&=a(-bd)d+(-ac)bc\\
&=-ab(d^2+c^2)\\
&=-ab.
\end{align*}

Answer (score 1):

Let $$u=\begin{pmatrix} a \\ b\end{pmatrix}.$$ The set of vectors orthogonal to $u$ is $$\Bigl\{\begin{pmatrix} bt \\ -at\end{pmatrix}:t\in\mathbb{R}\Bigr\}.\tag{$1$}$$  Only two vectors in this set have unit length: $$\begin{pmatrix} \pm b \\ \mp a\end{pmatrix}.$$ So $\begin{pmatrix} c \\ d\end{pmatrix}$ must be one of these two, and $ab+cd=0$ follows wither either choice from direct calculation.

To see why $(1)$ holds, we can just check that the solution set to the matrix equation $$\begin{pmatrix} a & b\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}x \\ y \end{pmatrix} = (0)$$ is $$ \Bigl\{\begin{pmatrix} bt \\ -at\end{pmatrix}:t\in\mathbb{R}\Bigr\}.$$